# Display a transparent Activity in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, transparent

How can I set (by code) an `Activity` to be transparent? I want the activity to become transparent when the user clicks a button. Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android

Comment: I saw that before...but I need to do this from activity,and not from xml.

Comment: do you understand what I want to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `setTheme (android.R.style.Theme_Translucent)`

But keep the api docs in mind:

> Set the base theme for this context. **Note that this should be called
>   before any views are instantiated in the Context** (for example before
>   calling setContentView(View) or inflate(int, ViewGroup)).

[Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.html#setTheme%28int%29)